# measuring the time of each operation in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, optimization

I have a SQL query in the format of tree (A⨝B)⨝(C⨝D)⨝(E⨝F)⨝(G⨝H)⨝(I⨝J) containing different joins.I want to know that is there any method that we can find the time for each join operation separately like how much time sub expression (A⨝B) can take. Or (C⨝D) can take. instead of whole expression. Or how can we find the time for only the sub expression (A⨝B)⨝(C⨝D). I have converted my SQL query into tree by using Java language. Thanks in Advance. I am using SQL server for implementing my queries

Comment: set statistics time on and set statistics io on for each of the subqueries that interest you come to mind

Comment: can you please tell me that how can i break this query into sub queries "select Oxygen.OxygenRatio, Water.WaterTemp,Oil.Oil_limit, Engine.EngineID  from Oxygen 
 JOIN Water ON Oxygen.OxygenID=Water.OxygenID JOIN Oil ON Oil.OilID=water.WaterID Join 
 Engine ON Engine.EngineID=Water.WaterID JOin Fuel ON Fuel.WaterID=Water.WaterID"

Comment: Just a heads up- these joins look wrong.

JOIN Oil ON Oil.OilID=water.WaterID

And also: Join Engine ON Engine.EngineID=Water.WaterID

Shouldn't it be "JOIN Oil ON Oil.WaterID=water.WaterID " or "JOIN Oil ON Oil.OilID=water.OilID"?

Comment: Have you used SSMS to view the execution plan (ctrl + L)?  If that isn't good enough, what else would you like to know about the query execution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need but you could try with DATEDIFF if you can split each operation.

```
DECLARE @timer1 DATETIME
DECLARE @timer2 DATETIME

SET @timer1 = GETDATE()
--stuff to measure here
SET @timer2 = GETDATE()
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond,@timer1,@timer2 ) AS time_spent
```

I think you can compare different queries and see which one does the best.

Comment: therefore if we do it like this "set statistics time on
select Oxygen.OxygenRatio, Water.WaterTemp,Oil.Oil_limit, Engine.EngineID  from Oxygen 
 set statistics time off
 JOIN Water ON Oxygen.OxygenID=Water.OxygenID JOIN Oil ON Oil.OilID=water.WaterID Join 
 Engine ON Engine.EngineID=Water.WaterID JOin Fuel ON Fuel.WaterID=Water.WaterID".. it gives us error

Comment: i don't know if you can measure between joins but you could measure different select statements separately and see the difference. First measure with one join, then with 2 joins, 3 joins, 4 joins...and different combinations. I think it depends on the amount of data stored in each table and the type of variables you join on ( but it seems like you join only on id which is the right way).

Comment: If you can add the SQL code for your tables and some fake data I can try to run some query's and post the code and my results.